# Is there any way to accept answers on the unowned questions that have been migrated from another SE site?

Tags: support, status-declined, migration, moderation

There are a number of questions that have been migrated over from the old Gadgets.SE as well as other sites that are attached to users that aren't registered here.  Some of them are quite old.  Is there any way to accept answers on these unowned questions so we don't have a bunch of "Unanswered" questions in the system?

**Update:**  I was thinking specifically about questions that have good answers that will never be accepted because the asker is a ghost.

Comment: Just a question: does this happen if the account is linked to both sites?

Comment: Nope, when the asker has an account on both sites and they are linked the new question is associated with the askers account on the new site.

Comment: Assuming they used the same credentials on both sites. If they use different OpenID providers, then the accounts *aren't* automatically linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the by, this **is not** going to be implemented. See:

[Allow mod accept for deleted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60212/allow-mod-accept-for-deleted-users/)

[Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)

Comment: You only have to upvote them to get them recognized as 'accepted' if the unanswered stat is what your aiming for

Answer (score 4):

maybe you can ask the meta.SO about this.

Answer (score 3):

Only if the person who originally posted it comes back and asks for the question to be linked to their new account. (I did that.)

But Louis has a good suggestion. I don't know what the thinking is for questions that are not likely to be ever answered and certainly never have an answer accepted. I suppose we could discuss getting rid of them on a case-by-case basis.

Of course, you could always upvote an answer; then it won't appear in the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: It's not possible and in all honesty, I don't think this will ever get 'fixed'

Comment: I think that if a question is an orphan the moderators should be able to accept the answers on behalf of the non-existent user.  I take it from your comment Ivo that this has been discussed already.  I'll do some searching before I post a redundant post on meta.SO, but do you mind giving me the readers digest version of "why" it'll never happen?

Comment: I agree that mods should be able to adopt these questions.

Answer (score 1):

If they're old, and unanswered, and not pulling in any traffic, then perhaps they should be deleted.